# How to calculate three constants in a linear recurrence problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Question: Verify that $x^3 - 3x^2 + 4 = (x^2 - 4x + 4)(x+1)$

And solve linear recurrence: $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = 0$, $f(2) = 14$, 
$f(n) =  3 f(n-1)- 4 f(n-3)$

The characteristic equation is already given in the verifying section and the roots can be determined from the $(x^2 - 4x + 4)(x+1)$

Roots are  $x=-1,2,2$

General form:
$$C_1(-1)^n + C_2(2)^n + C_3(2)^n \cdot n$$

For given, $$f(0) = 1 = C_1 + C_2$$
           $$f(1) = 0 = -C_1 + 2C_2 + 2C_3$$
           $$f(2) = 14 = C_1 + 4C_2 + 8C_3$$

I am having problem in calculating the three constants here. Please help.

Comment: This is a system of linear equations. Look up "How to solve a system of linear equations". There are different methods like Gauss-Elimination, or stepwiese substitution,..."

Comment: Seems straightforward, call those equations (1),(2),(3). (1)+(2) gives $3C_2+2C_3=1$. (3)-(1) gives $3C_2+8C_3=13$. Subtracting those two gives $6C_3=12$. Hence $C_3=2$, and so $C_2=-1,C_1=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said
$$f(1)=0=-C_1+2C_2+2C_3\Rightarrow C_3=\frac{C_1-2C_2}{2}$$
So we have
$$f(2)=C_1+4C_2+8(\dfrac{C_1-2C_2}{2})=5C_1-4C_2=14$$
Now just consider
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
C_1+C_2=1 \\ 
5C_1-4C_2=14
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
And solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is a system of linear equations. Look up "How to solve a system of linear equations". There are different methods like Gauss-Elimination, or stepwiese substitution,...